Unable to write to Windows file share "not enough space" yet drive has 10Gb free
I've got a system running Windows Server 2016 Standard.
It's got multiple file shares running from a common drive.
Periodically, I get an error when trying to save data to a file share on that drive.
"There is not enough space" - Which is weird, as the drive has 10Tb free on it..
When I work on the drive LOCALLY - it works fine, no errors. This only seems to be happening when accessing the drive via the file shares...
It should be noted: Quota's are NOT enabled. (I checked...twice!)
If I delete a stack of files, it seems to 'fix it'.... but the problem re-occurs...
Permissions aren't an issue as when I delete files, people can access and use the shares normally. And if one share on that drive starts throwing the error - they ALL do - for ALL users, including me, and I have full admin R/W on all shares...
Thoughts?

Access the server and:

Check for shadow copies (properties -> shadow copies tab)

Search for errors: chkdsk /f /r X: (replace X with the drive's letter) - note that if this your system disk, it will do the check only on reboot, and the -R option on a 10G disk will take hours

Before you do the next one, you should contact warn your mates (disconnections). Verify SMB using a terminal:
net stop server
net start server

Then, you should check for FS limitations. This ain't very likely to affect free space, but I would check that the the number of files and directories on the shared drive and ensure you're not hitting any NTFS limitations. It is a very large disk drive!

High i/o can cause these errors. Make sure nothing is wasting resources.
Use Task Manager or Resource Monitor to check for high disk usage or memory usage. Identify any processes that may be consuming resources excessively.

Make sure your network drivers are up to date, outdated or corrupt drivers can cause connectivity issues.
Open Device Manager -> expand Network adapters -> right-click your network adapter and select "update driver"

Check the logs:
Open the even manager -> windows logs > system, search for warnings and errors, even if they don't seem directly related to the issue, but pay most attention to "Disk" events.

Check if there are any hidden system files or directories consuming unexpected space. Windows lacks this tool, you might have to find a 3rd party program to search.

Recreate the shares (downtime), but before you do that, note the names and permissions! Remove the existing shares and recreate them with the same names and reviewed permissions.

If you can, you should modernize: Microsoft has put very little effort in the windows development for the last 25 years, weird issues are not uncommon.


